# Which person is telling the truth?

Tags: logical-deduction

A person was killed. There are 4 suspects.

A says C is the killer.
B says C is the killer.
C says that B is lying.
D says that it wasn't him.

There is only one person telling the truth. Who is this person, and why?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't supposed to be [lateral-thinking] rather than [logical-deduction]? Because there's another solution that I think fits more under the former tag than the latter, and I suspect that's what you're going for.

Comment: This really only asks who is speaking the truth. Didn't you also intend to ask who the killer is? Because that's also deducible, as @WhatsUp does.

Comment: Possibly related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57401/are-all-who-did-it-puzzles-the-same

Comment: What is the answer?

Answer (score 26):

The person telling the truth is:

> C

because:

> A and B cannot both tell the truth, so they are both lying.
>  B and C cannot both be lying, so C is telling the truth

and consequently, the killer is:

> D, because D is lying.

Answer (score 5):

This answer's a little eccentric, but bear with me. (Warning: this answer would fit a [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) puzzle, but since it is *not* explicitly a [non-lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/non-lateral-thinking) puzzle, just treat this as light-hearted entertainment.)

**There is no killer.**

> Suppose the narrator is telling the truth that there is only one person telling the truth.
>  Then the narrator is the truth teller, and all the others must be liars. But since B is among the liars, C's statement is true, which contradicts the supposition (we now have 2 truth tellers: the narrator and C).
>  So the narrator is a liar, and the initial statement "A person was killed" is false. Since nobody was killed, there is no killer. :P

Comment: But then you still haven't solved the puzzle of who's telling the truth.

Comment: @AdmiralJota There's an argument for C or D: no killer => B is lying and D isn't the killer. However, if the narrator is lying, the whole thing is compromised. There might not even be people called A, B, C or D.

Comment: Tsk. You had the perfect opportunity to claim that role for yourself...

Comment: @AdmiralJota Haha! That would have been icing on the cake. Ah, well, what’s done is done.

Answer (score 4):

Who tells the truth is:

> C

because

> otherwise there would be contradictions in AC, BC and BD pairs in terms of truth telling

Comment: I edited to hide your reasoning - nice answer - no change to the wording or anything, just the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> C.

because

> If C is lying, then B must be telling the truth. However, if B is telling the truth then A must also be telling the truth. This is a contradiction, so C must be telling the truth.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Note that I put some formatting into your answer so that the answer would not be obvious. You did a nice job of hiding your explanation though. I had to put some words in to make the formatting work.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate line of thinking:

> Either C or B must be telling the truth, otherwise C has a contradiction: If B doesn't tell the truth, then C *is*, but if C doesn't tell the truth, then *B* is.

Therefore

> D must be the killer, as he cannot be telling the truth.

This means

> A and B are lying, as C is *not* the killer. Therefore, C is the truth-teller.

Answer (score 2):

The person telling the truth is

> C

because

> if A is telling the truth, then B is telling the truth, and there can't be two people telling the truth, so they are both lying. C said that B is lying, which must be true because we just figured out that A and B are both lying. Therefore C is not the killer and is telling the truth.

Since there can only be one person telling the truth, and we know that

> C

is telling the truth,

> we know there can be no one else telling the truth, which means we now know that D is lying,

and is therefore the killer.

Answer (score 2):

> If D is lying, then D is the killer, therefore both A and B are lying, and C is telling the truth.
>
>  If D is telling the truth, then A, B and C are lying because there is only one truth teller. But if C is lying, B must be telling the truth. But now B is both lying and telling the truth - a contradicton!

Therefore:

> D is lying, so C is telling the truth and D is the killer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the person telling the truth is

> C

Here's another approach to figuring this out:

> If A is the killer, C and D are telling the truth.
>  If B is the killer, C and D are telling the truth.
>  If C is the killer, A, B, and D are telling the truth.
>  If D is the killer, only C is telling the truth.

From this we conclude (since we know there is only one truth-teller) that:

> The killer must be D, since that's the only case that gives us a single truth-teller, which is C.

Comment: Actually, rot13(vs Q yvrf, gura gur xvyyre qrsvavgryl zhfg or uvz, fb gur xvyyre vf Q).

Comment: If A is the killer, then wouldn't D be telling the truth as well?

Comment: @Kapten-N  Thanks, I've corrected my oversight.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one person is the killer.

> *My answer is **C is telling the truth** and **D is the killer***
>  
>  **A is a liar** -  C is the killer  (A & B both can't say the truth so we consider
>  they are both liars) 
>  **B is a liar** -  C is the killer  ( if they are liars that
>  means C is not a killer. ) 
>  **C telling truth** - B is lying      ( it is true B is
>  lying because C is not a killer if he was then A & B both were saying the truth) 
>  **D is a liar** - D says that it wasn't him (
>  C is telling truth and only one person is telling the truth that means
>  killer id D because he is not telling the truth. )

Answer (score 0):

C is telling the truth and
D is the killer.

A and B make the same claim, that C is the killer.
Both are right (telling the truth) or both are wrong (both are not telling the truth); Both can't be right because only one can be. Thus, both are wrong, i.e. C is not the killer. C's claim is that B is wrong, which agrees with the lies of A and B, that C is not the killer. If C's is the one telling the truth, then D's must be wrong, i.e. D is the killer, and not C.